# How to display image from the database to ionic?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have this code for showing image from the admin side to my ionic app :

```
<img ng-src="http://recipick.filantroph.com/recipick/{{search.r_image}}" class="full-image" >
```

the problem is I keep getting this error:

[image]

what should I do so that my would be display in my ionic app? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply navigate to http://recipick.filantroph.com/recipick/img/recipies/0feeb72d1cd27ef0f7bb3b0415de67eb.jpg in your browser, you'll see that the image does not exist. This isn't an ionic problem.

I noticed that you are required to log into http://recipick.filantroph.com/. Could it be that the images do not appear until you are authenticated? If this is the case, you should move the images to a public folder outside the authentication wall.

Answer (score 0):

I got the correct answer my path was wrong, just change :

```
<img ng-src="http://recipick.filantroph.com/recipick/{{search.r_image}}" class="full-image" >
```

**into**

```
<img ng-src="http://recipick.filantroph.com/{{search.r_image}}" class="full-image" >
```